# how to use implicit method in trait

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand the implicit method in Scala, in the SlashSyntax.scala I defined a customed operator method:

```
package com.example.hello.impl

object SlashSyntax {

  final class IntOps(private val intSrc: Int) {
    def \(a2: Int): Int = (intSrc.toString + a2.toString).toInt
  }

}

trait SlashSyntax {

  import SlashSyntax._

  implicit def intOps(src: Int) = new IntOps(src)
}
```

then in the main method I try to use the operator but it says cannot resolve symbol :

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import com.example.hello.impl.SlashSyntax._
    val s = 10 \ 2  //cannot resolve symbol \
  }
}
```

How can I use my own operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue caused by incorrect import.

```
import com.example.hello.impl.SlashSyntax._
```

Problem here is that you imported all members from `object SlashSyntax` instead of `trait SlashSyntax`. This happened because scala considered `com.example.hello.impl.SlashSyntax` as [path](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#paths). All paths can be composed only from `Stable members`. Traits are not `Stable members` but `objects` are stable members, so scala imported members from `object SlashSyntax`.

You can just move your implicit method to `object SlashSyntax` and this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to make the `IntOps` class an `implicit class`. Then

1. you don't need the `SlashSyntax` trait (or you can use it for other things)
2. the implicit is in the right place to be imported
3. the pesky `implicit conversion method ...` warning goes away

Answer (score 1):

1. Your object `SlashSyntax` doesn't extends trait `SlashSyntax` so your extension methods are not seen when you do `SlashSyntax._`.
2. Additionally you didn't do `import scala.languageFeatures.implicitConversions`. though you might have added `-language:implicitConversions` flag to scalac.
3. Sometimes lack of type annotation break things. Not in your case but it's good in general to these things there.

This works:

```
object SlashSyntax extends SlashSyntax {

  final class IntOps(private val intSrc: Int) {
    def \(a2: Int): Int = (intSrc.toString + a2.toString).toInt
  }

}

trait SlashSyntax {

  import SlashSyntax.IntOps

  implicit def intOps(src: Int): IntOps = new IntOps(src)
}
```